# ASP.NET CORE using asp-action in JS

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, asp.net-core, infobox

I'm trying to learn ASP.NET Core and writing simple project using Google Maps API and Infobox.js.
In index.cshtml I've got default code:

```
<a asp-action="Place" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Edit</a>
```

And everything works, this code leads me to

`localhost/places/Place/1`

Now I would like to add simillar link to infobox contentString (id = 1):

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function ()
{
contentString = '< a asp-action="Place" asp-route-id="' + id + '">detail< /a>';
boxText.innerHTML = contentString;
ibOptions.content = boxText;
var ib = new InfoBox(ibOptions); 
ib.open(map, marker);
map.panTo(ib.getPosition());
});
```

I can see the 'detail' label (it looks like a link - is blue and underlined) but i cannot click it - when I move mouse cursor over label - it does not change.

I write something like

```
contentString = '< a href="Place/' + id + '"> Details</a>';
```

It works (opens http://localhost/places/Place/1), but it is not the best way to do so, i think.

Could you help to change my code?
Sorry for using quotation marks but I cannot do it another way.

Comment: You can't do that. Tag Helpers are a Razor feature, not HTML feature. Tag helpers only work with views rendered by the server (which are processed by razor to be specific)

Comment: Thank you for information. So what should I do to create an Url in infobox? I should use @Url.Action somehow?

Comment: @Url.Action is also a razor feature. Just use relative urls and set the base url in via `<base href="~/">` inside your view or `_Layout.cshtml`. Your controllers are unlikely to change and even if they do, you'd have to rename it manually (whether you use `asp-action` or `asp-controller`)

Comment: Thank you for your attention.
I've added base href in _Layout.cshtml. What should I do in Javascript section? It should be as I shown previously:
    
'<a href="Place/' + id + '">Details </a>';

?